# How to check DateTime format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want to create a function to find a DateTime format of string type.
For Example: -

I have a string as '07/09/2016 12:00 AM' and want it in DateTime format of this string and it should be like : - MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt format.

So, when I pass the DateTime as string to this function then function returns me a DateTime format using SQL function.

Comment: Uh, would the implicit assumption be that a string formatted like that is always MM/dd ? Because I don't see any reason that couldn't be dd/MM. How would your hypothetical function parse which is which?

Comment: What options you have thought of and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want the input formatted and returned as a string? Or do you want to return the detected format of the input?

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `TRY_CONVERT` to convert your date string into a bona fide datetime.  Then, we can use `FORMAT` to display the datetime in the format you want to see.

```
SELECT FORMAT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '07/09/2016 12:00 AM'),
              'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt', 'en-US')

07/09/2016 12:00 AM
```

### Demo

Comment: @DaleBurrell Maybe you misread my answer.  I am already returning a literal string.  Dates don't really have an internal format.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear what `tt` meant.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope this will work for you

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(19))
```

Also try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 101) + right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),GETDATE(),100),8)
```

Comment: @AmIT try this.